# Very customizable and mobile friendly javascript color picker

Tags: javascript, color

I'm implementing my own user interface for a home automation server in HTML and JavaScript and I need a color picker for lighting fixtures. The problem with all existing color pickers I saw is, that they're designed to cover the whole RGB range in a detailed way. For lighting control I don't need this since RGB(w) LEDs can't display that much colors. So I actually need control about all pick-able colors.

Here's a draft what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image: color picker draft]

I could start implementing it by myself but when it comes to mobile friendly functionality I think it would get pretty complicated.

Is a color picker like this out there? Or is there at least any library which is useful for creating a mobile friendly implementation?